# using python to extract archives of different types to a specific folder with using a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, 7zip

I'm trying to extract archives of different types (such as: *.7zip, *.V3P, *.Q4P) to a specific folder with using a subprocess.

```
import subprocess

archname = "E:\\temp\\payments.zip"
dir7z = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"

def extractfiles(archname):
    system = subprocess.Popen([dir7z, "x", archname])
    return (system.communicate())

extractfiles(archname)
```

This code extracting files to the project folder, but I want extract them to the specific folder as "E:\temp\".
I know 7zip command on the Windows command line:

```
7z x E:\temp\payments.zip -o"E:\temp\"
```

Please, help me implement that 7zip command from Python

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067097/7zip-commands-from-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using the "os" library:

```
import os
os.system("""7z x E:\\temp\payments.zip -o"E:\\temp\\"""")
```

Basically runs the given command like you would in command prompt

Comment: I tried this one. displays: '"C:\Program" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Process finished with exit code 0' but I can't find extracted files in the E:\\temp\\

Comment: Well that's weird, since it basically runs the command in the command prompt as you would from keyboard, to clarify, does the command work when you enter it manually?